# Ruby warning message

Tags: ruby

When I run rdoc in terminal, it works, but only with a heap of warnings saying that:

```
unable to convert "\xA9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for tmp/cache/assets/CC7/4D0/sprockets%2Fd7d58761510113ba5435f0baba05573b, skipping
```

I get a similar message when installing the telephony engine freeSWITCH.

What does it mean, should I be worried, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't be too worried.  At worst, some of rdoc's generated documentation will not show up, but most people just go and read the docs on the web anyways.

If you run into this in your own application code however, I would suggest reading Yehuda Katz's article on [Ruby 1.9's String Encoding](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/).

Read it twice... there's a lot in there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in a Unix based environment, adding `export LC_CTYPE="utf-8"` to your ~/.bash_profile should resolve things.

Otherwise, you may want to try the following combination:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
unset LC_ALL
```

EDIT:

The error messages indicate that the environment is configured to read ASCII, but the code being run is using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Thanks, but what does it **mean**?

Comment: It sets your default character encoding to UTF-8. The error message means that the code that runs is trying to use UTF-8 characters, but is in ASCII encoding mode and cannot read those UTF-8 characters. No need to worry, it won't break anything.

Comment: @JWH, padde is correct. The problem is mostly innocuous, but in some circumstances, it can cause fatal errors in certain Ruby gems. Did modifying your .bash_profile resolve the issue?

Comment: @zeantsoi Sadly not! I've asked a similar question on the unix and linux stackexchange, but all suggestions welcome!

Comment: @JWH, did you try restarting your machine?

Comment: @zeantsoi  *Egg on my face.* I'll try that. Thanks!